# Use DropNet with generated access token

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropnet

I'm trying to find a way to use DropNet with generated access token but can't find  solution. Following code throws exception and says "Access token not found".

```
var client = new DropNetClient("App Key", "Secret");
client.UserLogin = new UserLogin { Token = "Generated Access Token" };
client.GetFile(...);
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue. I'm using the old version of library which supports OAuth1 authorization only and it doesn't support authorization with generated access token. Moreover old version of library has no API to switch from OAuth1 to OAuth2